# Create a new windows registry key using c++

Tags: c++, registry

I'm trying to create a new registry key in the windows registry using C++.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
HKEY hKey;
    LPCTSTR sk = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\OtherTestSoftware");

    LONG openRes = RegCreateKeyEx(
            HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
            sk,
            0,
            NULL,
            REG_OPTION_BACKUP_RESTORE,
            KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
            NULL,
            &hKey,
            NULL);

    if (openRes==ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Success creating key.");
    } else {
        printf("Error creating key.");
    }

    LPCTSTR value = TEXT("OtherTestSoftwareKey");
    LPCTSTR data = "OtherTestData\0";

    LONG setRes = RegSetValueEx (hKey, value, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)data, strlen(data)+1);

    if (setRes == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Success writing to Registry.");
    } else {
        printf("Error writing to Registry.");
    }

    //RegDeleteKey(hKey, sk);

    LONG closeOut = RegCloseKey(hKey);

    if (closeOut == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Success closing key.");
    } else {
        printf("Error closing key.");
    }
```

I'm able to successfully open an existing key using a very similar code snippet (basically replace RegCreateKeyEx with RegOpenKeyEx).  I would imagine that one or more of the arguments I'm passing into RegCreateKeyEx is causing the trouble.  I'm honestly not sure where things might be getting fouled up since all of the error codes i've trapped show success.  For reference, here is the function signature for RegCreateKeyEx:

```
/*
 * LONG WINAPI RegCreateKeyEx(
      __in        HKEY hKey,
      __in        LPCTSTR lpSubKey,
      __reserved  DWORD Reserved,
      __in_opt    LPTSTR lpClass,
      __in        DWORD dwOptions,
      __in        REGSAM samDesired,
      __in_opt    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
      __out       PHKEY phkResult,
      __out_opt   LPDWORD lpdwDisposition
    );
 */
```

Any thoughts would be great!

thanks,
brian

Comment: Where exactly is your error occurring (I assume at the RegCreateKeyEx() call, but we shouldn't have to guess), and what does GetLastError() return?

Comment: Are you intending to try to delete the key you just created?

Comment: Instead of REG_OPTION_BACKUP_RESTORE you should pass REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE (=0). You can consult on the behavior of such options from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724844(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Michael, that Delete call is commented out the version of this that I've been testing - the post is updated to reflect this.  Good catch.  Also, does GetLastError() return something different than the ERROR_SUCCESS code returned by Create?  All of those return successfully...

Comment: Just place a few of these in my code:

DWORD in1 = GetLastError();
 LPTSTR buff1 = "";
 FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER, NULL, in1, 0, buff1, 100, NULL);
 printf(buff1);

It seems that no errors were thrown anywhere.  Am I calling FormatMessage incorrectly?

Comment: Don't use GetLastError() after calling RegCreateKeyEx. The function return value tells you why it failed; look up this value in <winerror.h>, or see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382.aspx

Comment: I think I was confused (or am confused) - you say you're getting no error returns? Then what exactly is the behavior you're seeing that you do not like? (and sorry about the useless suggestion regarding GetLastError())

Comment: on which windows version are you trying this app? Since, vista and later, windows have changed registry concept, may be the problem is virtualization. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756960.aspx

Answer (score 15):

I've been compiling my own personal Function Library for years. One part of this deals entirely with registry access, see the CreateRegistryKey function the [Registry.Cpp](https://github.com/NTDLS/NSWFL/blob/master/NSWFL_Registry.Cpp) file.

If you are interested, you can grab the [entire library here](https://github.com/NTDLS/NSWFL).

Comment: I'm actually gonna take a stab with this - looks very friendly thanks!

Comment: Did not Define IsWinNT

Comment: That's in my library, but these days - you'd be safe just assuming your app is not running on Windows 95 or 98.

Comment: I have several compilations errors when trying to use/build the library

Comment: @bananabr such as?

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, you've specified the `REG_OPTION_BACKUP_RESTORE` option in the call to `RegCreateKeyEx`, which means that you're opening the key in order to perform a backup or restore. Ordinarily, you would use `REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE` instead.

What operating system are you running? In Windows 2000/XP, the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` registry hive is not writeable by non-administrator users, so `RegCreateKeyEx` will fail with an access denied error (error 5). This also applies to Vista, if your application has a `requestedExecutionLevel` entry in its manifest. If you're running Vista, and your application doesn't specify a `requestedExecutionLevel` (or if it doesn't have a manifest at all), access to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` will be virtualised, so `RegCreateKeyEx` should succeed. See [Registry Virtualization in Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530198.aspx) in MSDN for more details.

There are some more problems with the code you've posted, which will only become apparent if you compile your project with `UNICODE` defined. This line:

```
LPCTSTR data = "OtherTestData\0";
```

should be

```
LPCTSTR data = TEXT("OtherTestData\0");
```

and this line:

```
LONG setRes = RegSetValueEx(hKey, value, 0, REG_SZ,
    (LPBYTE)data, _tcslen(data)+1);
```

should be:

```
LONG setRes = RegSetValueEx(hKey, value, 0, REG_SZ,
    (LPBYTE)data, (_tcslen(data)+1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
```

because the `cbData` parameter in `RegSetValueEx` is the length of the data in bytes, not characters.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I made your changes with one exception: (_tcslen(data)+1) * sizeof(TCHAR) changed to (strlen(data)+1) * sizeof(TCHAR) as it wouldn't compile the first way.  Again, no error codes returned, just doesn't do what I expect it to.  Thanks for the hints though, seems like I may be getting closer!

Comment: Add #include <tchar.h> to use _tcslen().

Comment: If Unicode were enabled, I don't think `LPCTSTR data = ""` would compile.

Answer (score 2):

The first clue is your use of `REG_OPTION_BACKUP_RESTORE`. You probably don't want to use that flag, as I believe it requires a special "backup" privilege that you need to enable beforehand. Normal applications won't want to do that.

Comment: Yes; not only do you need the privilege, but you need to explicitly enable it through a security API call; unless you knew that already, you probably don't want to be using it. :)

Comment: Changed to REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, does not seem to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is the [reason why you can cannot create a new key](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257176), with your code.

These links might be of help.

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-378884.html
http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-275250.html

As a sidenote, always try GetLastError() to get the error message.

I have not tested either of them.